# Finding max in mysql when column is varchar

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar field that is code of letters and is auto incremented (manualy), so after A is B until after Z becomes AA and so on.

My issue is when I hit AA and I try to select MAX of this field:

```
SELECT MAX(letter) from jobs
```

Returns Z instead of AA. This is correct if you are ordering names, but I have a code. There's a way to get this right?

Answer (score 9):

Try this one.  This will force it to weight longer strings as being higher than shorter strings:

```
SELECT letter
FROM jobs
ORDER BY LENGTH(letter) DESC, letter DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Edit:  Yup, forgot to sort DESC to get the MAX...

Comment: +1, that's better than my subquery solution. One thing to keep in mind if you want to avoid the performance killer of per-row functions is to have another (indexed) column called letter_len which is populated by an insert/update trigger, then use that in the order by clause. That will amortise the cost of the calculation (done when the data changes) across all reads, substantially speeding up queries.

Answer (score 2):

This may help? Sort them by length first, then by letter.

```
SELECT letter FROM jobs
ORDER BY LENGTH(letter) DESC, letter DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: That's still going to give Z for the input set [A..Z,AA].

Comment: Sorry, edited after I realized that I was stupid for not reading correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're after the max of the *longest* field, I would start with something like the following. I'm not sure if the syntax is correct. Basically you have to ignore all but the longest column values.

```
select max(letter) from jobs
where len(letter) = (
    select max(len(letter)) from jobs
)
```

Whatever solution you choose, consider the option of adding another column to hold the letter length and have it controlled by an insert/update trigger (assuming MySQL *has* that).

By indexing that column, you can greatly accelerate your queries since you remove the per-row functions during `select`. The right time to incur the cost is when the data changes so that the cost of the calculation is amortised across all reads.

This won't work in situations where the database is written more often than read, but they're relatively rare in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a maximum length for your field?  If so, can you also stomach right-justifying the data in that field?  The chances are that the answers are (1) empirically 'yes', and 5 might be an upper length, and (2) not really.  However, were you able to say 'yes' to both, then you would be able to use this (where the boxes are blanks):

- '☐☐☐☐A'
- ...
- '☐☐☐☐Z'
- '☐☐☐AA'
- '☐☐☐AB'
- ...
- '☐☐☐BA'
- ...
- '☐☐☐ZZ'
- '☐☐AAA'

Realistically, that probably isn't going to be OK for you, and therefore it won't help.